Strange behaviour with tikz[babel] with pdfLaTeX
I noticed a strange behaviour of label processing in tikz when used with the tikzlibrary babel and with pdfLaTeX. Here is the code
\documentclass[frenchb]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}

\def\Command#1{#1}
\Command{\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}}
\end{document} 

With that, I get  twice

which is what I want. It works with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. It works with the babel option [safe=none] or without it.
If now I use the babel library in tikz:
\documentclass[frenchb]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}

\def\Command#1{#1}
\Command{\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}}
\end{document} 

the first result is correct but the second is now

with pdfLaTeX. Everything remains correct with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX!
In reality I use a more complex \Command (!) but the fact is: however simple it is, as soon as the call is made inside the command, the tikz label processing fails with pdfLaTeX.
Is there an explanation to this strange behaviour ?

Then I believe the problem is the same as always. The \Command fixes its argument's catcodes (here, : is made active by babel) but the babel library changes them (w/o any effect for the input) but then TikZ only expects other :s (as part of an old workaround which is why it works without the babel library) and trips up. The best approach will depend on what \Command does and whether you need the shorthands inside the command (and the TikZ diagram).

You can negate the effect of the babel library locally. Or you can emulate its effect locally, if you need it at all. Note that frenchb is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Also, you should be using T1 encoding for French. Your log/terminal tells you both these things when you compile with pdfTeX. (T1 isn't relevant to the other engines, but you shouldn't use frenchb regardless.)

I've encountered this kind of problem before, and from what I understand it's due to the : (colon) character in the tikz command. In French typography, this character is managed in such a way as to leave a space after it, which is not the case in English.
For a reason best explained by a specialist, the \shorthandoff{:} and \shorthandon{:} commands solve this problem.
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}

\shorthandoff{:}
\def\Command#1{#1}
\Command{\tikz{\node[label={above:\(^\ominus\)}] (C) at (0,0) {C} ;}}
\shorthandon{:}
\end{document} 


Thanks ! But why does it works fine with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX ?

I'm not a specialist in the babel package and its \shorthandoff and \shorthandon commands, nor in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. Ask a new question and a specialist will be able to answer you.
